# Why won't the last h2 heading show content?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm editing a site for a client, and nearly everything was fine until I ran around one problem.
The client asked me to design a homepage with animated fade-ins and outs.

Everything will show properly, but no matter what I put at the last line, it just won't show. Right now it only shows the  `>` I tried putting  `<p>` there, also won't show. Does anybody have an idea?

```
 <!-- wp:columns -->
<div class="wp-block-columns"><!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>About Alfa laboratory</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Alfa laboratories is a Dutch company. We design and manufacture so-called research chemicals. Profit from our high quality standards and our fast and reliable way of shipping. All our orders are sent out without logo's or any other fancy design, to ensure the anonymity of the customer. </p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:quote -->
<blockquote class="wp-block-quote"><p><strong>Important note:</strong> <em>Our products are made and designed for laboratory use. None of the products sold on this website are designed nor made suitable for consumption.We do not accept any responsibility</em> <em>that comes forth out of incorrect use of our products</em>.<em> The customer and the customer alone are responsible for the way of use. Only the customer can be held accountable in case of damage or mis-use of our products</em>.</p></blockquote>
<!-- /wp:quote --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column -->
<div class="wp-block-column"><!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>Questions &amp; answers </h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:yoast/faq-block {"questions":[{"id":"faq-question-1609497058636","question":["How long does it take before I receive my order?"],"answer":[{"type":"em","props":{"children":["That depends on the shipping location.",{"type":"br","props":{"children":[]}},"- Netherlands 1 - 2 working days.",{"type":"br","props":{"children":[]}},"- Rest of Europe 3 - 5 working days.."]}}],"jsonQuestion":"How long does it take before I receive my order?","jsonAnswer":"\u003cem\u003eThat depends on the shipping location.\u003cbr/\u003e- Netherlands 1 - 2 working days.\u003cbr/\u003e- Rest of Europe 3 - 5 working days..\u003c/em\u003e"},{"id":"faq-question-1609497074632","question":["How long does it take to process my payment?"],"answer":[{"type":"em","props":{"children":["That depends from which bank you are transferring funds. We receive domestically made payments instantly. It takes 1 working day to process payments done from the rest of Europe."]}}],"jsonQuestion":"How long does it take to process my payment?","jsonAnswer":"\u003cem\u003eThat depends from which bank you are transferring funds. We receive domestically made payments instantly. It takes 1 working day to process payments done from the rest of Europe.\u003c/em\u003e"},{"id":"faq-question-1609497081616","question":["From where do you ship?"],"answer":[{"type":"em","props":{"children":["We ship all our orders from the the Netherlands."]}}],"jsonQuestion":"From where do you ship?","jsonAnswer":"\u003cem\u003eWe ship all our orders from the the Netherlands.\u003c/em\u003e"}]} -->
<div class="schema-faq wp-block-yoast-faq-block"><div class="schema-faq-section" id="faq-question-1609497058636"><strong class="schema-faq-question">How long does it take before I receive my order?</strong> <p class="schema-faq-answer"><em>That depends on the shipping location.<br/>- Netherlands 1 - 2 working days.<br/>- Rest of Europe 3 - 5 working days..</em></p> </div> <div class="schema-faq-section" id="faq-question-1609497074632"><strong class="schema-faq-question">How long does it take to process my payment?</strong> <p class="schema-faq-answer"><em>That depends from which bank you are transferring funds. We receive domestically made payments instantly. It takes 1 working day to process payments done from the rest of Europe.</em></p> </div> <div class="schema-faq-section" id="faq-question-1609497081616"><strong class="schema-faq-question">From where do you ship?</strong> <p class="schema-faq-answer"><em>We ship all our orders from the the Netherlands.</em></p> </div> </div>
<!-- /wp:yoast/faq-block --></div>
<!-- /wp:column --></div>
<!-- /wp:columns -->

<!-- wp:heading {"textAlign":"center","editorskit":{"devices":false,"desktop":true,"tablet":true,"mobile":true,"loggedin":true,"loggedout":true,"acf_visibility":"","acf_field":"","acf_condition":"","acf_value":"","migrated":false,"unit_test":false}} -->
<h2 class="has-text-align-center animate-fade">The  best sold products in 2020</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:paragraph {"align":"center","style":{"typography":{"fontSize":18}}} -->
<p class="has-text-align-center" style="font-size:18px"> A list of our best sellers in the last year. You can buy all of them with a special -5% discount </p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:shortcode -->
[product_category category="cathithone,dissociative" per_page="6" columns="6" orderby="title" order="asc"]
<!-- /wp:shortcode -->

<!-- wp:columns {"className":"has-2-columns"} -->
<div class="wp-block-columns has-2-columns"><!-- wp:column {"width":"34%","className":"animate-fade-right","editorskit":{"devices":false,"desktop":true,"tablet":true,"mobile":true,"loggedin":true,"loggedout":true,"acf_visibility":"","acf_field":"","acf_condition":"","acf_value":"","migrated":false,"unit_test":false}} -->
<div class="wp-block-column animate-fade-right" style="flex-basis:34%"><!-- wp:cover {"url":"https://alfa-labs.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Depositphotos_79001162_s-2019.jpg","id":7530,"dimRatio":0,"overlayColor":"yith-proteo-editor-custom-color-2","contentPosition":"center center"} -->
<div class="wp-block-cover has-yith-proteo-editor-custom-color-2-background-color" style="background-image:url(https://alfa-labs.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Depositphotos_79001162_s-2019.jpg)"><div class="wp-block-cover__inner-container"><!-- wp:paragraph {"align":"center","textColor":"yith-proteo-editor-custom-color-2"} -->
<p class="has-text-align-center has-yith-proteo-editor-custom-color-2-color has-text-color">Discover the world of </p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph {"align":"center","textColor":"yith-proteo-editor-custom-color-2","style":{"typography":{"fontSize":35}}} -->
<p class="has-text-align-center has-yith-proteo-editor-custom-color-2-color has-text-color" style="font-size:35px"><strong>Research chemicals</strong></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --></div></div>
<!-- /wp:cover --></div>
<!-- /wp:column -->

<!-- wp:column {"width":"66%","className":"animate-fade-left","editorskit":{"devices":false,"desktop":true,"tablet":true,"mobile":true,"loggedin":true,"loggedout":true,"acf_visibility":"","acf_field":"","acf_condition":"","acf_value":"","migrated":false,"unit_test":false}} -->
<div class="wp-block-column animate-fade-left" style="flex-basis:66%"><!-- wp:cover {"url":"https://alfa-labs.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Depositphotos_167730812_l-2015-min.jpg","id":7512} -->
<div class="wp-block-cover has-background-dim" style="background-image:url(https://alfa-labs.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Depositphotos_167730812_l-2015-min.jpg)"><div class="wp-block-cover__inner-container"><!-- wp:paragraph {"align":"center","style":{"typography":{"fontSize":18}}} -->
<p class="has-text-align-center" style="font-size:18px">Enjoy a special -5% discount on every category</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph {"align":"center","style":{"typography":{"fontSize":35}}} -->
<p class="has-text-align-center" style="font-size:35px"><strong>SAVE 5% WITH COUPON "2021"</strong></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph --></div></div>
<!-- /wp:cover --></div>
<!-- /wp:column --></div>
<!-- /wp:columns -->

<!-- wp:spacer {"height":20} -->
<div style="height:20px" aria-hidden="true" class="wp-block-spacer"></div>
<!-- /wp:spacer -->

<!-- wp:heading {"textAlign":"center"} -->
<h2 class="has-text-align-center animate-fade">Browse popular products</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading --> 

<!-- wp:paragraph {"align":"center"} -->
<p class="has-text-align-center">A list of popular products right now</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:yith/yith-wc-productslider {"className":"animate-fade-up"} -->
<div class="wp-block-yith-yith-wc-productslider animate-fade-up"><span class="yith_block_60a7f5871601fdebb0753d1981d46a86">[yith_wc_productslider id="216"]</span></div>
<!-- /wp:yith/yith-wc-productslider -->
<!-- /wp:spacer -->

<h2 class="has-text-align-center animate-fade-left"> Browse our categories </h2>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use the Css and Color Of p Tag
Example

```
style="font-size:35px; color:#fff;">
```